# Store multiple EditText values in Hashmap

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, android-edittext

I am new to android. I have a listview with 3 Edittext in each row.Right now i am storing it with different three hashmap but i want to store it in one.So how can i store this 3 EditText values in one LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Describe your use case a little more.  You probably don't want to store any more references to your UI controls than you absolutely need, so maybe abstracting out a model object and write some code that binds your model data to and from the EditText fields.  I can give a better example if you provide more information about your particular case

Comment: `ListView` work with Adapters, which already store the data in a list. You might just use data from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below code for store all edittext values into hashmap.

```
LinkedHashMap lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
hash.put("key1", editText1.getText().toString());
hash.put("key2", editText2.getText().toString());
hash.put("key3", editText3.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for reply...can i store 3 values on one key?

Comment: @Niyati No it is not possible and if it is necessary to store all edittext value in one key then use string concatenation for that.

Comment: Thank you very much.. i ll try in that way. And one more question can i store arraylist on the key in hashmap?

Comment: @Niyati Make Arraylist of Hashmap and try.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> myHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

ListView lv = new ListView(this);
EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
EditText et3 = new EditText(this);

et1.setText("EditText1");
et2.setText("EditText2");
et3.setText("EditText3");

lv.addView(et1);
lv.addView(et2);
lv.addView(et3);

for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
    EditText child = (EditText) lv.getChildAt(i);
    myHashMap.put(i, child.getText().toString());
}
```

Feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you and ..Sorry my mistake in asking question Please see the edited question.i have a three EditText in one Row. So how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can look at below example and use hash.put in adapter getview() when you edittext textchanged.

LinkedHashMap lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap();

hash.put("key1", youredittexvalue);

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thank you for reply...I am already do that but it only store one EditText value in one HashMap and i want to store all 3 EditText Value in one HashMap.